# How to replace @action decorator when changing from ViewSet to ListApiView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have to rewrite certain view that is ReadOnlyModelViewSet ("GroupViewSet") to ListApiView.
The ReadOnlyModelViewSet has two methods with @action decorators.
Since @action decorators do not work within ListApiView views, what is the best way to achive the same rerouting functionality within ListApiView?

ReadOnlyViewSet view:

```
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
serializer_class = GroupSerializer
queryset = Group.objects.all()
filterset_class = GroupFilter
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

@action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
def specs(self, request):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    specs_id = queryset.values_list('spec_id', flat=True)
    specs = DictSpec.objects.filter(id__in=specs_id)
    serializer = DictSpecSerializer(specs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
def subspecs(self, request):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    subspecs_id = queryset.values_list('subspecs__id', flat=True)
    subspecs = DictSubSpec.objects.filter(id__in=subspecs_id)
    serializer = DictSubSpecSerializer(subspecs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```